# Android setclickable for custom view not work

Tags: android

I need to create a custom view to make a counterfeit button, and what's more, that button's enable or not depends on another checkbox.

[image]

I'd like the button stay un-clickable when the checkbox was not be checked, but it seems not work as expected.

The control logic of checkbox was in `MainActivity` :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.use_so_botton)
    val cusBtn = findViewById<CusButton>(R.id.cus_btn_in_use)
    val chkBox = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.check_box_in_use)
    chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener{
        _, isChecked ->
            cusBtn.isClickable = isChecked

    }

    cusBtn.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Gotta you, custom view", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

The layout of `MainActivity` is simple, named the ConstraintLayout to `use_so_botton.xml`:

```
<kot.bignerd.linearlay101.CusButton
        android:id="@+id/cus_btn_in_use"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="66dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:image="@drawable/sun"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:text="Yo haha" />

<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_box_in_use"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Use!"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cus_btn_in_use"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="66dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="68dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="117dp" />
```

The `<kot.bignerd.linearlay101.CusButton` tag inside the layout is the custom view's ConstraintLayout xml itself:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/budhha"
        tools:src="@color/colorPrimary"
        >
</ImageView>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        tools:text="Caption of the Image"
        android:text="ButtText"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ImageView01"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textColor="#000000">
</TextView>
```

And the `CusButton.kt` to get the parameters:

```
class CusButton(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {
    init {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.so_button, this)

        val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.ImageView01)
        val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.TextView01)

        val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CusButton)
        imageView.setImageDrawable(attributes.getDrawable(R.styleable.CusButton_image))
        textView.text = attributes.getString(R.styleable.CusButton_text)
        attributes.recycle()
    }
}
```

Right now, even if the checkbox was unchecked, we could still click the button and got a toast.

I was wondering how to disable the counterfeit button until the checkbox was checked.

Comment: you need to also set 'setEnabled' to true. view.setEnabled(true);

Comment: @Shahin Thanks, please reply it as a one line answer, in that case I could accept it as answer.

Comment: your welcome. wish you the best <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem is simply `view.setEnabled(true);`

Explanation:
For enabling Clicks and Touch events on any view

To Enable Click Listener Response

```
myView.setClickable(true);

<MyView
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
```

these attributes are gonna enable "ClickLlistener" Response. for example, Buttons are already set to be pressed and don't need any "setEnabled"

But a Custom View or just a View that isn't set to be Clicked or Touched or Pressed we need 'setEnabled' as true in code

```
myView.setEnabled(true);
```

Also, when you write `view.setOnClickListener` the view automatically is `setEnabled(true)` but clicks don't work cause it needs `setClickable(true)` to start listening to the response of click events